# Contact Form 7 Display Block for one group of list items

Tags: html, css, forms, checkbox

I am aware I can use the following code

```
span.wpcf7-list-item { display: block; }
```

But this would effect every list item on every form.

How would I create a class that I can add to the checkbox field that would only effect that group of checkboxes?

**Edit with answer:**

Create a class or id and add wpcf7-list-item after the class or id name

```
.check-block .wpcf7-list-item { display:block; }
```

The form would look like [checkbox my-name class:check-block "option 1" "option 2" ]

Comment: Try to add class to the form like 'test' and then try with .test .check-block-list-item {...} This will edit only the form with class 'test' and checkbox with class 'check-block-list-item'

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to try .check-block .wpcf7-list-item {...}? The class .check-block-list-item doesn't effect the list items. The class is added to the [checkbox] field but doesn't make the list items block, just the checkbox as a whole. I added a link to the form page I am working on.

Comment: I figured it out, .check-block .wpcf7-list-item { display:block; } works.